# Split away Selection Service from o.e.ui.workbench bundle

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, osgi, selection, equinox

I want to use **Selection Service** feature from the eclipse RCP in my swing project. Currently the o.e.ui.workbench bundle which contains the related interface is around 3.7 MB, that's way too huge for our requirement

1. Is there any way to split it the workbench to get only the selection service
2. Are there distros already for this
3. Is it leagal to do so. Are there any licencse issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like it would be that hard to do it yourself, and that's pretty much what you would have to do.  I know of no distros that do this however.

It's certainly legal to do so; you can freely use or modify any part of Eclipse until the EPL.  If you split it without modifications then you have no obligations under the license.  However if you extend it (and redistribute your code), then you need to make available your code that extends it (which can be done using an Eclipse bug report for example).